# Will postgres index work for both directions with NULLS LAST?

Tags: postgresql

If I create index for nullable timestamp column `due_date` with `DESC NULLS LAST`, will then index also work for `ASC NULLS LAST` query?

Maybe it's will be just less performant? Or I need to create second index?

In postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-ordering.html) we can see that backward direction scan nulls became first:

> An index stored in ascending order with nulls first can satisfy either
> ORDER BY x ASC NULLS FIRST or ORDER BY x DESC NULLS LAST depending on
> which direction it is scanned in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; the index order must be identical or exactly opposite to the `ORDER BY` clause. A `DESC NULLS LAST` index will only work for `ORDER BY ... DESC NULLS LAST` or `ORDER BY ... ASC NULLS FIRST`.

Comment: So only solution is two indexes?

Comment: If you need to support different sort orders, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Building two indexes, or just letting it do the sort, are currently the only clean solutions.

There is another unclean method which is to use UNION ALL.

```
(select * from foobar where due_date is not null order by due_date asc nulls first)
   union all 
(select * from foobar where due_date is null)
```

PostgreSQL would be within its rights to return these rows in a different order than you want, but currently it doesn't happen to do that.